# Wait for jQuery show() to finish before continuing function?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, show

I can't make my div visible with the jquery show() until my function is over! It actually works in IE/FF but not in Chrome. How can I make sure my element is visible before continuing with my function?

Here's my code:

```
function doOperation(){
    $("#progressbar_area").show();
    (...)
}
```

Comment: With the code you have there the element _should_ be shown directly afterwards and if that doesn't work in Chrome it would be considered a bug. Are you sure you don't have something like 'slow' or a speed inside the show?

Comment: No, I don't use the speed parameters. By the way, when I do use them, my div just doesn't show up in any browser (FF/IE/Chrome) until the function is over. Really odd.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a callback to show:

```
$("#progressbar_area").show(speed, function() {});
```

The callback function will be called when the animation is complete.

Comment: im using scrollTop() and cant be display none so im doing this to wait to continue but, even that works, is animating the show from left and doing weird stuff...

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it would be better to put the rest of your function in the callback parameter to `show`:

```
$("#progressbar_area").show("fast", function() {...} );
```

The caveat here is that the callback is fired (separately) for each element that is in the selector. Fine if you are only showing one item, though.

Comment: hopefully there will only be one element with an id of progressbar_area!