# JQuery show() only works after my function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery's `show()` to display a busy indicator while my function (with some heavy number crunching) runs. However, the indicator only appears when the function has finished, or not at all when I uncomment the `hide()` which I have at the end of my function.

I'm using `display: none;` to hide the indicator in the first place.

```
var convert = function() {
    $("#working").show();
    // ...
    $("#working").hide();
};
```

Comment: I doubt provided code is enough! Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: post code or jsfiddle so that we can provide you solution.

Comment: in javascript, anything that's not asynchronous can be assumed to be run in zero-time

Comment: I suggest working with promises when you have a long operation in your 'action' function

Comment: Please refer this link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031470/wait-for-jquery-show-to-finish-before-continuing-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031470/wait-for-jquery-show-to-finish-before-continuing-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because browser works like a single threaded application, including script execution and script execution.

Even though you are setting the display, the actual rendering will not happen till the current script execution is completed.

One simple hack is to use a small timer to delay the large task and give the rendering operation a chance to update the UI

```
var convert = function() {
  $("#working").show();
  setTimeout(function() {
    // ...
    $("#working").hide();
  });
};
```